# Is there a way to find the maximum number of promotes in accurev?

Tags: accurev

Is there a way to find the maximum number of promotes by a user in a stream , in Accurev? 
Some information like
User - Count# Of Promotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
accurev hist -s <stream> -u <user> -k promote -a | grep transaction | wc -l
```

Comment: Some formatting trouble there. Try this:  accurev hist -s STREAMNAME -u USERNAME -k promote -a | grep transaction | wc -l